# Where to store access tokens?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, session, asp.net-web-api

I am building a RESTful web api. Once a user is authenticated and authorized, they are given an access token which contains:

- user_id
- timestamp
- permissions

My question is if it is better to encrypt those tokens using a symmetric algorithm and pass it to the client OR just pass a unique hash that points to user's session in my `session table`. So basically:

**Token stored on the client's side** - when te server receives the token, it is being decrypted and all the data is in memory.

**Data about session is stored in a database and the client receives a hash** - when the server receives the hash, the session data is being looked up in the database and taken from there.

Which solution is better for a large service, handling millions of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a scalability perspective, it is definitely better to produce a token containing the information, sign it on the server, then pass it back to the client to store and return with each request. By signing it on the server, you make it immune to the user tampering with the data. The only requirement is that all servers in your estate have the same key to sign and check the signature on the tokens.

There's a standard for doing this, called [JSON Web Tokens](http://jwt.io/), which has implementations in pretty much every framework going, including [support in .NET from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: If we don't store any server-side state, we have no way to invalidate the JWT when the user logs out. In effect our service has no logout function, which may be a security problem especially if we set the expiration time too far in the future. On the other hand if we set the expiration time too soon, we may have a problem with users still being logged in but not having a valid JWT. This may lead to awkward error-handling and user workflow issues. Is there a way to address this problem? Is providing an api method "refresh_token" a good idea?

Comment: The service becomes, in effect, session-less, so indeed the concept of being "logged in" or "logged out" isn't really the right way to think about it from the API perspective - it's about having confidence that the user is who they say they are. As soon as you store some sort of session state, it becomes much harder to scale as that has to be shared by all servers. There's no problem having an API method to refresh the token.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd send the token back. But I wouldn't rely on the token to provide information; rather I'd use it as a hash to get the information for the specific user again.

Caching should be able to take care of any performance concerns.

The reasons I'd do this as opposed to your two options are:

1. If the token contains information about authentication and authorization, it can be manipulated client-side. All someone would need is the decryption key. Better to get (and validate) this information on the server where it is much harder to manipulate.
2. Session always has a performance impact so I'd recommend avoiding it. Plus, using session can encourage some "bad" practices when developing the site itself (e.g. storing too much or everything in session, using session to work around design flaws, etc.).